# error: incompatible types: PesoR_Male cannot be converted to Context(AlertDialog custom)

Tags: android

The error is, error: incompatible types: PesoR_Male cannot be converted to Context

I'm using a Tablayout and in a layout I want to show a custom alert that returns a value and gives me an error when creating the customized alert in this line 33 and 40:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder BLunes= new AlertDialog.Builder(PesoR_Male.this);

Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

This a de code:

```
public class PesoR_Male extends Fragment {
TextView lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.pesor_male,container,false);

    lunes=view.findViewById(R.id.Lunes);
    martes=view.findViewById(R.id.Martes);
    miercoles=view.findViewById(R.id.Miercoles);
    jueves=view.findViewById(R.id.Jueves);
    viernes=view.findViewById(R.id.Viernes);

    lunes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder BLunes= new AlertDialog.Builder(PesoR_Male.this);
            View mView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rutinas,null);

            ImageView img1= mView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            BLunes.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog =BLunes.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: use `AlertDialog.Builder BLunes= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());`

Comment: Brandor just replace your code with mine , here is the code snippet :- https://codeshare.io/5e4JX4 , it will work. :)